# Calculating average for each beacon in list

Tags: java, android

I have a method called onEddystonesFound that runs approximately every second. As a parameter it has a list of beacons ordered by RSSI values, so the closest beacon can be found in index[0].

Each beacon has a UID which can be called with eg. beacon.get(0).instance and a RSSI value which can be called with eg. beacon.get(0).instance

For the 4 nearest beacons, I want to collect the 10 latest RSSI values for each beacon and calculate an average and a standard deviation of the 10 values to remove outliers and calculate a new average of the remaining values. How can I do this the best way?

I have tried something like the code below, but I don't believe it is the correct way of doing it. Can anybody help with this please?

```
private Map<String, List<Eddystone>> beaconMap = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, Double> averageMap = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void onEddystonesFound(List<Eddystone> beacon) {
      //populates map
      for (int i = 0; i < beacon.size(); i++) {
           beaconMap.put(beacon.get(i).instance, beacon);
      }

         //loops through map
         for (List<Eddystone> e : beaconMap.values()) {
              int sum = 0;
              //loops through list in map
              for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
                   sum = sum + e.get(i).rssi;
              }

              if (e.size() >= 10) {
                 double average = sum / e.size();
                 for (int i = beaconMap.size() - 10; i < beaconMap.size(); i++) {
                      List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
                      keys.addAll(beaconMap.keySet());
                      averageMap.put(keys.get(i), average);
                 }

              }
}
```

Comment: And the question is? (as *[Can anybody help with this please?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)* is not a real question)

Comment: The question is: How to calculate an average and a standard deviation based on 10 rssi readings for each beacon

Comment: avg - by summing x and dividing it by their number ... std dev by summing (x-avg)^2 then divide by their number then taking sqrt